# PDF Print Preview Failure on Android 7

Tags: pdf, printing

An Android phone with Android 7, trying to use the HP Print Service Plugin (Android 8 was the version that brought in the default print service that makes this obsolete).

Certain PDF files (all from the same sender, it appears) will not render correctly in the print preview dialog (and will not print, either). Instead of lines of text, you only see horizontal grey blocks where text should be. This is similar to how the Facebook website behaves while it's downloading content - showing a placeholder of sorts.

The same PDFs on my Samsung S7 and another random unbranded Android 8 tablet work fine.

Is there anything I might be able to do, or at least an explanation I can give for the issue?

Many thanks in advance.